# How to check TLS version of request

Tags: java, spring-boot, retrofit2, okhttp, tls1.3

I have `okhttp3.OkHttpClient` and I make REST request using Retrofit2.

```
interface WebService {
    @GET("/httptwo")
    public Call<String> executeRequest();
}


//in these 2 methods I initialize server IP, SSLContext, keystore, truststore and all the stuff.
OkHttpClient client = getClient();
Retrofit retrofit = getRetrofit(client);

//make call
WebService service = retrofit.create(WebService.class);
Call<String> call = service.executeRequest();
try {
    Response<String> response = call.execute();
    String responseBody = response.body();
    System.out.println(responseBody);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I make request to my dummy Server.

```
@RestController
class SecureServiceController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/httptwo")
    public String httpTwoHandler() {
        String httpVersion = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getProtocol();
        System.out.println("http version: " + httpVersion);
        
        return "Hello from " + httpVersion;
    }
```

}

As you can see, I can check version of http protocol.
But **how can I check version of TLS that was used?**

Answer (score 3):

```
response.handshake().tlsVersion()
```

Will be for example `TlsVersion.TLS_1_2`.

See https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-tls-version/

Comment: Just small note for future generations: here is used okhttp3.Response. I work with Retrofit2, so I had retrofit2.Response<T>. To get okhttp3.Response I used myRetrofitResponse.raw()